# How to give Drawer in BottomBar Page

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have Bottom bar page to show all my page i created, but the to call the page that i created i must call the class first like this

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:project_kel_bumira/pages/Chat.dart';
import 'package:project_kel_bumira/pages/Profile.dart';
import 'package:stylish_bottom_bar/model/bar_items.dart';
import 'package:stylish_bottom_bar/stylish_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'Journal.dart';
import 'HomePage.dart';
import 'icon.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const BottomBar());
}

class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Stylish Bottom Navigation Bar Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // useMaterial3: true,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const AnimatedBarExample(),
      // home: const AnimatedBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedBarExample({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimatedBarExample> createState() => _AnimatedBarExampleState();
}

class _AnimatedBarExampleState extends State<AnimatedBarExample> {
  dynamic selected;
  var heart = false;
  PageController controller = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: false, //to make floating action button notch transparent
      //to avoid the floating action button overlapping behavior,
      // when a soft keyboard is displayed
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

      bottomNavigationBar: StylishBottomBar(
        items: [
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 33,
            ),
            selectedIcon: const Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 40,
            ),
            selectedColor: Color(0xff4852A1),
            backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
            unSelectedColor: Colors.grey,
            title: Text(
              'Home',
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            showBadge: true,
          ),
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.explore,
              size: 33,
            ),
            selectedColor: Color(0xff4852A1),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            title: Text(
              'Explore',
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          BottomBarItem(
            
              icon: const Icon(

                Icons.chat_rounded,
                size: 29,
              ),
              selectedIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.style,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              selectedColor: Color(0xff4852A1),
              title: Text(
              'Chat',
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontSize: 16),
            ),),
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 33,
            ),
          
            selectedIcon: const Icon(
              Icons.person,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
            selectedColor: Color(0xff4852A1),
            title: Text(
              'Profile',
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        hasNotch: true,
        fabLocation: StylishBarFabLocation.center,
        currentIndex: selected ?? 0,
        onTap: (index) {
          controller.jumpToPage(index);
          setState(() {
            selected = index;
          });
        },
        option: AnimatedBarOptions(
          // iconSize: 32,
          barAnimation: BarAnimation.transform3D,
          iconStyle: IconStyle.animated,
          // opacity: 0.3,
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(
            Size(70, 70)), // ubah nilai Size sesuai kebutuhan
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 200,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
              );
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff4852A1),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.calendar_month_outlined,
            size: 35,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            HomePage(),
            Iconss(),
            Chat(),
            Profile(),
          ],
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//
//Example to setup Bubble Bottom Bar with PageView
class BubbelBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const BubbelBarExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BubbelBarExample> createState() => _BubbelBarExampleState();
}

class _BubbelBarExampleState extends State<BubbelBarExample> {
  PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  var selected = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: controller,
        children: const [
          // Home(),
          // Add(),
          // Profile(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: StylishBottomBar(
        option: BubbleBarOptions(
          barStyle: BubbleBarStyle.horizotnal,
          // barStyle: BubbleBarStyle.vertical,
          bubbleFillStyle: BubbleFillStyle.fill,
          // bubbleFillStyle: BubbleFillStyle.outlined,
          opacity: 0.3,
        ),
        items: [
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.abc),
            title: const Text('Abc'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.read_more),
          ),
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.safety_divider),
            title: const Text('Safety'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          ),
          BottomBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.cabin),
            title: const Text('Cabin'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ],
        fabLocation: StylishBarFabLocation.end,
        hasNotch: true,
        currentIndex: selected,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selected = index;
            controller.jumpToPage(index);
          });
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

So I Want to Give A drawer in My Homepage, but my drawer are under my BottomNavigationBar.

This my HomePage() code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:project_kel_bumira/pages/BottomBar.dart';

import 'ProfileTeacher.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String displayName = user!.displayName ?? '';

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 30),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Hi, $displayName!',
                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                      fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 140),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/Sapiens1.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5),
            child: Text(
              "What Do You Feel?",
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                  fontSize: 27,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: Color(0xff4852A1)),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    hintText: "Search Anything Here",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Color(0xff4852A1),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 10),
            child: Text(
              "Mind Scape Services",
              style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                fontSize: 27,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Color(0xffF85C3D),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 70,
                      height: 70,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/Icon.png")),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        "Consulting",
                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
                        child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/Icon2.png")),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Journal",
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
                        child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/Icon3.png")),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Content",
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
                        child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/Icon4.png")),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Other",
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Our Conselor",
                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                    fontSize: 27,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    color: Color(0xffF85C3D),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileTeacher(),));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "See All",
                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                        fontSize: 17,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Color(0xff4852A1),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 220,
                          height: 300,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/dokter1.png"),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffE1EEF7),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            "Mrs. Cassandra",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 120),
                          child: Text(
                            "Counselor",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: Color(0xff9E9E9E)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 220,
                          height: 300,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/dokter2.png"),
                            width: 120,
                            height: 120,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffE1EEF7),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
                          child: Text(
                            "Mr. Ricky",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 125),
                          child: Text(
                            "Counselor",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: Color(0xff9E9E9E)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 220,
                          height: 300,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/dokter3.png"),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffE1EEF7),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            "Mrs. Gunawan",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 120),
                          child: Text(
                            "Counselor",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: Color(0xff9E9E9E)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        width: 250,
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text("Ini Judul Drawer"),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I Just want my Drawer is on top my bottom bar and homepage, but the homepage still under bottom bar.